# SAPUI5 Add parameters to starting URL

Tags: sapui5

My initial page has 2 parameters which are defined in `manifest.json`. I have already routed them correctly, but the problem is, on start-up, I would like to have a default value for those two parameters already.

I checked on the `neo-app.json`, and the `WelcomeFile` field has the `index.html`, I tried to add the parameters there but it just breaks my app because it cannot find the `index.html/param1/param2` which makes sense.

Is there a way to add a default starting parameter to the UI5 application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this two parameters as optional and on patternMatched of your main controller set with default value if it's empty.

To set parameter as optional change { to :

```
"pattern": "routepath/:parameter:",
```